# Check if a column exist or not in where clause

Tags: mysql

I'll try to explain my issue the best way.

First I show you my sql tables:

**Host** : This table contains all the hosts, some of those can be templates depending on the value of register

--- ID --- --- host_name --- register ---

```
 1         host1            1
 2         host2            1
 3         template1        0
 4         template2        0
```

**Host template** : This is the association table which links the host with the templates, several templates can be linked to an host and an host might not have template.

--- ID --- --- id_host --- --- id_template ---

```
1             1              3
2             1              4
```

I want to retrieve all my hosts with their associated templates even if they don't have any :

--- host_name --- --- template ---

```
    host1       template1, template2
    host2            NULL
```

I tried to do this with left join, I only get the host1 in result :

```
SELECT h.host_name, GROUP_CONCAT( ht.host_name ) 
FROM host_template sht
LEFT JOIN host h ON h.id = sht.id_host
LEFT JOIN host ht ON ht.id = sht.id_template
WHERE ht.register =0
GROUP BY host_name
```

Another way was to add OR clause in the left join. In the result, i have host2 but with all the templates...

```
SELECT h.host_name, GROUP_CONCAT( ht.host_name ) 
FROM host_template sht
LEFT JOIN host h ON h.id = sht.id_host OR sht.id_host IS NULL 
LEFT JOIN host ht ON ht.id = sht.id_template OR sht.id_template IS NULL 
WHERE ht.register =0
GROUP BY host_name
```

I think i'm really close to found the solution but I need a bit help from you guys. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reordering the join may do the job :

```
SELECT h.host_name, GROUP_CONCAT( ht.host_name ) 
FROM host h
LEFT JOIN host_template sht ON h.id = sht.id_host
LEFT JOIN host ht ON ht.id = sht.id_template
WHERE h.register <>0
GROUP BY h.host_name
```

Comment: Or changing the first join to a right join would have worked - as long as you changed the where clause to _h.register <>0_

Answer (score 0):

I think there's a problem with this line :

```
LEFT JOIN host h ON h.id = sht.id_host OR sht.id_host IS NULL
```

You may try an INNER JOIN without the OR :

```
INNER JOIN host h ON h.id = sht.id_host
```

[image: SQL join]

Try this (added a second argument for where) :

```
SELECT h1.host_name, GROUP_CONCAT( h2.host_name ) FROM host_template ht
LEFT JOIN host h1 ON h1.id = ht.id_host
LEFT JOIN host h2 ON h2.id = ht.id_template 
WHERE h1.register =0 and h2.register = 0
GROUP BY h1.host_name
```

Comment: I edited the response for more visibility.
Check your where clause. Try to add .register = 0 for your two joins.

Comment: I already tried this before, it doesn't seem to work anyway. I found the solution but thank you for the time you spent for me ;)